# Internet Cyber stalking for sabotage

Tags: criminal-law

I have a problem with a cyber stalker whose sole intention is to ruin me personally and professionally.  How can one protect themselves legally?

Comment: What exactly is this cyber stalker doing? Posting defamatory information on a public website? I.e., posting false statements that are claimed as true? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-is-defamation-defined

Comment: When I post a vacancy for a position on linkedin in a business I'm trying to start he will for example find out who responded and mess the deal up like say Im incompetent and uneducated to all my prospects

Comment: How is he finding out who responded to your posting? Do you have emails where he states you are "incompetent and uneducated"?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* be the victim of defamation (which includes libel)

> Libel is a method of defamation expressed by print, writing, pictures,
>   signs, effigies, or any communication embodied in physical form that
>   is injurious to a person's reputation, exposes a person to public
>   hatred, contempt or ridicule, or injures a person in his/her business
>   or profession. [Definition of Libel](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/libel)

but *it depends* on what exactly is in the communications that this person is writing and emailing to others. He must be making false statements that he claims are true. That can be libel.

[There are four criteria used today for Defamation](http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/defamation) in the United States:

> 1. The statement was false, but was claimed as true.
> 2. The statement must have been made to a third, previously uninvolved party.
> 3. The statement must have been made by the accused party.
> 4. The statement caused harm.

If you are not a public figure - like a politician or Hollywood star - the threshold is lower for defamation, i.e. it's easier for him to libel you.

We can't offer legal advice here, and I am not a lawyer, but you can contact a lawyer or a free legal help clinic with the contents of the emails and be able to state (or be able to prove) what you feel are the damages to your business ventures. A lawyer can make the call if this is indeed defamation and your what your options might be.